# recursive function - subsequence

Tags: c++, recursion, boolean, subsequence

I'm trying to get a recursive Function, which should compare two int arrays and say wether array2 is a subsequence of array1.
My Problem is now that i dont know when to set the return value of an bool recursive function.
I'm glad for every help.

```
int array1 [] = {1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6,7,8,9,10};
int array2 [] = {2,4,6,8};
int l1 = 10;
int l2 = 4;


bool isSubset ( int p1 , int p2) {

   while (p1 <= l1) {
       if (array1[p1] == array2[p2]) {
            isSubset(p1 + 1, p2 + 1);
        } else {
            isSubset(p1 + 1, p2);
        }
    }
}


int main (void) {
    if ( isSubset(0,0))
        cout << "yes" << endl ;
    else
        cout << " no " << endl ;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return `true` if you have found all items of `array2` (that is, if `p2 == l2`). If you've reach the end of the `array1`, but there is still some items of `array2` that you haven't found yet, return `false`.
Otherwise, collect all results of recursive calls of `isSubset` and if there is at least one `true`, return `true`.
The code:

```
bool isSubset ( int p1 , int p2) {
    if(p2 >= l2) return true; //  we have found all array2's items
    if(p1 >= l1) return false; 
    bool result = false;

    while (p1 < l1 && !result) { // whether we have found the subsequence - break the loop
        if (array1[p1] == array2[p2]) {
            result |= isSubset(p1 + 1, p2 + 1);
        } else {
            result |= isSubset(p1 + 1, p2);
        }
        ++p1;
    }
    return result; 
}
```

And you don't need a while loop here, this will work too:

```
bool isSubset ( int p1 , int p2) {
    if(p2 >= l2) return true; //  we have found all array2's items
    if(p1 >= l1) return false; 
    if(array1[p1] == array2[p2]){
        return isSubset(p1 + 1, p2 + 1);
    }else{
        return isSubset(p1 + 1, p2);
    }
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
bool isSubset ( int p1 , int p2) {
    if(p2 >= l2) return true; //  we have found all array2's items
    if(p1 >= l1) return false; 
    return isSubset(p1 + 1 , p2 + (array1[p1] == array2[p2]));
}
```

p.s. `isSubset` is bad name in this case because this algorithm is order-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int subs(string input,string output[]){
    if(input.length()==0){
        output[0]="";
        return 1;
    }
    string smallstring=input.substr(1);
    int smallans=subs(smallstring,output);
    for(int i=0;i<smallans;i++){
        output[i+smallans]=input[0]+output[i];
    }
    return 2*smallans;
}

int main(){
    string input;
    cin>>input;
    int len=input.length();
    int osize=pow(2,len);
    string *output=new string[osize];
    
    int count=subs(input,output);
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        cout<<output[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here we are returning all substrings of a given string, I think this is the easiest solution.

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073) Then, edit your code to include the required **standard** headers - otherwise, you are likely to attract downvotes.